# Multiple animations to an image view in different time

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to animate an imageview in a spiral path while rotating. I have used an animation set and added these animations as the first step so that imageview will move to right first and then to below. (Width and height is the width and height of the screen which I have taken using widthPixels and heightPixels methods in DisplayMetric type attribute)

```
        animation1 = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f, Animation.ABSOLUTE, width-180,
        Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f);
        animation1.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        animation1.setDuration(5000);

        RotateAnimation ranim = new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f); //, 200, 200); // canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2);
        ranim.setDuration(5000);
        ranim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

        animation2 = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE, width - 180, Animation.ABSOLUTE, width - 180,
                Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f, Animation.ABSOLUTE, height - 300);
        animation2.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        animation2.setDuration(7000);
        animation2.setStartOffset(5000);

        RotateAnimation ranim2 = new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f); //, 200, 200); // canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2);
        ranim2.setDuration(7000);
        ranim2.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        ranim2.setStartOffset(5000);
```

When I run this only animation2 + ranim2 is exectuing where the imageview will move from the top right corner of the screen to bottom right corner of the screen while rotating. Can someone tell me how to do this animation?
Thankyou :)

Comment: please post your animationSet code also. then only we can conclude the problem here.

Comment: animSet1.addAnimation(ranim);
animSet1.addAnimation(animation1);
animSet1.addAnimation(ranim2);
animSet1.addAnimation(animation2);

star.startAnimation(animSet1);

Answer (score 0):

You can use AnimationSet for this.

Comment: Thanks. I have used an AnimationSet but only the second animation is executing. Its like the second animation is replacing the frist one(i.e animation1+ranim). May be because they both start executing at once. How can I give a time to start each of these animations in the animation set?

Comment: you can set put hold animation between two...So i think you can get output as you want.

Comment: how can I put hold animation? Can you please give me an example.. Thanks :)